# Error with xticks stacking on top of each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

Purpose of the following code is to take the information of Time and Volume from the file: 'Pond 1 Data.txt' and present the information in graphical form.

Pond 1 Data.txt file docs link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jTbXyLk_V5H2DREcjVAMF3jFQ661qTfN5f8UEe_aXUM/edit?usp=sharing

I have been running data on notepad, here is a snippet of how text is supposed to look:
[Notepad snippet of txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWc3.png)

Somewhere within either the x list or the xticks function an error occurs in the graph beginning with the "2020-11-20 23-00" value that makes all values/ticks after display as a single tick.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

with open('Pond 1 Data.txt', 'r+') as rf:
    x = [] 
    y = []
    for line in rf:
        lenline = len(line)
        if("Current_Time:" in line and lenline<=34):
            year = line[14:18]
            month = line[19:21]
            day = line[22:24]
            hour = line[25:27]
            minute = line[28:30]
            second = line[31:33]
            date = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day), 
                   int(hour), int(minute))
            time = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')
            x.append(time)
        if("Pond 1 volume:" in line): 
            line = line[15:38]
            line.strip("\n")
            data = float(line)
            y.append(data)
        elif("Pond 1 volume:" not in line or "Current_Time:" not in line):
            pass

plt.plot(x ,y)
plt.title("Pond 1 Time vs Volume")
plt.ylabel("Volume (ft^3)")
plt.yticks([0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000])
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.xticks(["2020-03-20 23-00","2020-04-20 23-00","2020-05-20 23-00","2020-06-20 23-00",
            "2020-07-20 23-00","2020-08-20 23-00","2020-09-20 23-00","2020-10-20 23-00",
            "2020-11-20 23-00","2020-12-20 23-00","2021-01-20 23-00","2021-02-20 23-00",
            "2021-03-20 22-59"], 
           ['MAR 20, 2020', 'APR 20, 2020', 'MAY 20, 2020', 'JUN 20, 2020', 'JUL 20, 2020',
            'AUG 20, 2020', 'SEP 20, 2020', 'OCT 20, 2020', 'NOV 20, 2020', 'DEC 20, 2020',
            'JAN 20, 2021', 'FEB 20, 2021', 'MAR 20, 2021'],
            horizontalalignment = 'right',rotation = 40)

plt.savefig("Pond 1 Graph.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the output graph with current code:]

### Sample Data: **Pond 1 Data.txt**

```
ï»¿Current_Time: 2020-03-20 23:00:01
Pond 1 volume: 65249.99250000122
Pond 1 depth: 4.999999482758705
Current_Time: 2020-03-23 00:00:00
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 4.906645551100275e-07
Current_Time: 2020-03-24 22:00:02
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-03-26 21:00:04
Pond 1 volume: 7748.7820527009735
Pond 1 depth: 1.0343987622552395
Current_Time: 2020-03-28 23:00:04
Pond 1 volume: 7748.7820527009735
Pond 1 depth: 1.0343987622552395
Current_Time: 2020-03-31 00:00:04
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.0627778394201304e-07
Current_Time: 2020-04-01 23:00:06
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-04 01:00:06
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-06 03:00:06
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-08 05:00:06
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-10 03:00:08
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-12 02:00:09
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-14 02:00:10
Pond 1 volume: 24467.320199507853
Pond 1 depth: 2.187401393069507
Current_Time: 2020-04-16 04:00:10
Pond 1 volume: 24467.320199507853
Pond 1 depth: 2.187401393069507
Current_Time: 2020-04-18 06:00:10
Pond 1 volume: 24467.320199507853
Pond 1 depth: 2.187401393069507
Current_Time: 2020-04-20 04:00:12
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-22 05:00:12
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-04-24 04:00:14
Pond 1 volume: 0.49022313392073635
Pond 1 depth: 0.008222954699441502
Current_Time: 2020-04-26 06:00:14
Pond 1 volume: 3562.1240821853353
Pond 1 depth: 0.7009475441227898
Current_Time: 2020-04-28 07:00:14
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.19003228287754e-06
Current_Time: 2020-04-30 06:00:16
Pond 1 volume: 59.84725579932221
Pond 1 depth: 0.09085589635986642
Current_Time: 2020-05-02 08:00:16
Pond 1 volume: 59.84725579932221
Pond 1 depth: 0.09085589635986642
Current_Time: 2020-05-04 09:00:16
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.801407813705303e-07
Current_Time: 2020-05-06 08:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-08 10:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-10 12:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-12 14:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-14 16:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-16 18:00:18
Pond 1 volume: 12270.720485433509
Pond 1 depth: 1.346256585202311
Current_Time: 2020-05-18 17:00:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-05-20 16:00:21
Pond 1 volume: 1334.4376963800853
Pond 1 depth: 0.42902257739482025
Current_Time: 2020-05-22 15:00:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-05-24 15:00:23
Pond 1 volume: 32.91161347852669
Pond 1 depth: 0.06737605578831317
Current_Time: 2020-05-26 16:00:23
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.94734794258503e-07
Current_Time: 2020-05-28 14:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-05-30 16:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-01 18:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-03 20:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-05 22:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-08 00:00:25
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-09 22:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-12 00:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-14 02:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-16 04:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-18 06:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-20 07:00:27
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-22 05:00:29
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 4.056088302779804e-07
Current_Time: 2020-06-24 04:00:31
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-26 06:00:31
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-28 07:00:31
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-06-30 04:00:34
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-02 06:00:34
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-04 08:00:34
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-06 10:00:34
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-08 11:00:34
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-10 10:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-12 12:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-14 14:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-16 16:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-18 18:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-20 20:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-22 22:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-25 00:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-27 02:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-29 03:00:36
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-07-31 02:00:38
Pond 1 volume: 115.47512614220015
Pond 1 depth: 0.12620461008148914
Current_Time: 2020-08-02 03:00:38
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 7.9968710813635e-07
Current_Time: 2020-08-04 02:00:40
Pond 1 volume: 3.608974735297746
Pond 1 depth: 0.02231119939989238
Current_Time: 2020-08-06 04:00:40
Pond 1 volume: 3.608974735297746
Pond 1 depth: 0.02231119939989238
Current_Time: 2020-08-08 06:00:40
Pond 1 volume: 3.608974735297746
Pond 1 depth: 0.02231119939989238
Current_Time: 2020-08-10 08:00:40
Pond 1 volume: 3.608974735297746
Pond 1 depth: 0.02231119939989238
Current_Time: 2020-08-12 09:00:40
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 2.163864400086919e-07
Current_Time: 2020-08-14 07:00:42
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-08-16 07:00:43
Pond 1 volume: 1140.5084386068434
Pond 1 depth: 0.39662514894211853
Current_Time: 2020-08-18 09:00:43
Pond 1 volume: 1140.5084386068434
Pond 1 depth: 0.39662514894211853
Current_Time: 2020-08-20 10:00:43
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 2.5319637547655963e-07
Current_Time: 2020-08-22 08:00:45
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 4.790932641530677e-07
Current_Time: 2020-08-24 07:00:47
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-08-26 09:00:47
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-08-28 10:00:47
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-08-30 08:00:49
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-09-01 07:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 57.014713440272224
Pond 1 depth: 0.08867975194797734
Current_Time: 2020-09-03 09:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-05 11:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-07 13:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-09 15:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-11 17:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-13 19:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-15 21:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-17 23:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-20 01:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-22 03:00:51
Pond 1 volume: 958.4244796556234
Pond 1 depth: 0.3635883385815609
Current_Time: 2020-09-24 02:00:52
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-09-26 02:00:53
Pond 1 volume: 14538.399290361693
Pond 1 depth: 1.502648226921496
Current_Time: 2020-09-28 00:00:56
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-09-30 02:00:55
Pond 1 volume: 881.0672483164242
Pond 1 depth: 0.34860653609644493
Current_Time: 2020-10-02 04:00:55
Pond 1 volume: 881.0672483164242
Pond 1 depth: 0.34860653609644493
Current_Time: 2020-10-04 06:00:55
Pond 1 volume: 881.0672483164242
Pond 1 depth: 0.34860653609644493
Current_Time: 2020-10-06 08:00:55
Pond 1 volume: 881.0672483164242
Pond 1 depth: 0.34860653609644493
Current_Time: 2020-10-08 10:00:55
Pond 1 volume: 881.0672483164242
Pond 1 depth: 0.34860653609644493
Current_Time: 2020-10-10 09:00:56
Pond 1 volume: 511.579217622631
Pond 1 depth: 0.26563631285381484
Current_Time: 2020-10-12 09:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-14 11:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-16 13:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-18 15:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-20 17:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-22 19:00:57
Pond 1 volume: 6984.103154641852
Pond 1 depth: 0.9814909948919799
Current_Time: 2020-10-24 17:00:59
Pond 1 volume: 292.78769750145534
Pond 1 depth: 0.20095897591349518
Current_Time: 2020-10-26 19:00:59
Pond 1 volume: 1166.1035930344974
Pond 1 depth: 0.40105096297267506
Current_Time: 2020-10-28 18:01:00
Pond 1 volume: 5950.952000343318
Pond 1 depth: 0.9059917028122253
Current_Time: 2020-10-30 18:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 17637.35565820843
Pond 1 depth: 1.7163693557385125
Current_Time: 2020-11-01 20:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 17637.35565820843
Pond 1 depth: 1.7163693557385125
Current_Time: 2020-11-03 22:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 17637.35565820843
Pond 1 depth: 1.7163693557385125
Current_Time: 2020-11-06 00:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 17637.35565820843
Pond 1 depth: 1.7163693557385125
Current_Time: 2020-11-08 02:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 17637.35565820843
Pond 1 depth: 1.7163693557385125
Current_Time: 2020-11-10 03:01:01
Pond 1 volume: 9935.457323732497
Pond 1 depth: 1.1852039533608618
Current_Time: 2020-11-12 02:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6583.154421219349
Pond 1 depth: 0.9529015161487209
Current_Time: 2020-11-14 04:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-16 06:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-18 08:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-20 10:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-22 12:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-24 14:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-26 16:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-28 18:01:03
Pond 1 volume: 6588.829408631737
Pond 1 depth: 0.9533121505377964
Current_Time: 2020-11-30 16:01:05
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-02 18:01:05
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-04 16:01:07
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-06 18:01:07
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-08 20:01:07
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-10 22:01:07
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-12 20:01:09
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-14 18:01:11
Pond 1 volume: 6184.722248001895
Pond 1 depth: 0.9236152541266487
Current_Time: 2020-12-16 16:01:13
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-18 18:01:13
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-20 20:01:13
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-22 22:01:13
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2020-12-24 20:01:15
Pond 1 volume: 7933.52813330577
Pond 1 depth: 1.0471398712624669
Current_Time: 2020-12-26 22:01:15
Pond 1 volume: 7933.52813330577
Pond 1 depth: 1.0471398712624669
Current_Time: 2020-12-29 00:01:15
Pond 1 volume: 7933.52813330577
Pond 1 depth: 1.0471398712624669
Current_Time: 2020-12-31 01:01:15
Pond 1 volume: 6198.714000924121
Pond 1 depth: 0.9246594154661616
Current_Time: 2021-01-02 00:01:17
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-04 02:01:17
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-06 04:01:17
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-08 02:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-10 04:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-12 06:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-14 08:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-16 10:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-18 12:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-20 14:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-22 16:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-24 17:01:19
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-26 14:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-28 16:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-01-30 18:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-01 20:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-03 22:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-06 00:01:22
Pond 1 volume: 270.9767988881944
Pond 1 depth: 0.1933290205620333
Current_Time: 2021-02-07 22:01:24
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-10 00:01:24
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-11 22:01:26
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-14 00:01:26
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-15 22:01:28
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-17 23:01:28
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.7861147582366446e-07
Current_Time: 2021-02-19 22:01:30
Pond 1 volume: 3828.374784417441
Pond 1 depth: 0.7266716551527282
Current_Time: 2021-02-21 23:01:30
Pond 1 volume: 0
Pond 1 depth: 1.0235230312261844e-07
Current_Time: 2021-02-23 22:01:32
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-25 23:01:32
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-02-27 21:01:34
Pond 1 volume: 261.725
Pond 1 depth: 0.19
Current_Time: 2021-03-01 19:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-03 21:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-05 23:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-08 01:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-10 03:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-12 05:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-14 07:01:36
Pond 1 volume: 1745.1311626213485
Pond 1 depth: 0.4906197576213802
Current_Time: 2021-03-16 06:01:37
Pond 1 volume: 0.0
Pond 1 depth: 0.0
Current_Time: 2021-03-18 05:01:38
Pond 1 volume: 4965.519068871698
Pond 1 depth: 0.8275863591875701
Current_Time: 2021-03-20 07:01:38
Pond 1 volume: 3587.585039846105
Pond 1 depth: 0.7034481614453492
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Hopefully I have satisfied the suggested edits, though I don't know what "mre" is referring to. Also thank you for the help.

Comment: `time = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')` is the primary issue. You should plot a datetime on the x-axis, not a string. `x.append(date)`, and then format the xtick labels.

Comment: `import matplotlib.dates as mdates` `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` `ax.plot(x ,y)` `monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%B %d, %Y')` `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)` `_ = plt.xticks(rotation=45)` [See code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKtgH.png)

Comment: The code is functional, but verbose: 1: `with open('d:/data/Pond 1 Data.txt', 'r+') as rf: data = rf.readlines()` 2: `time = list(map(datetime.fromisoformat, [v.split(': ')[1].strip() for v in data[0::3]]))` 3: `depth = list(map(float, [v.split(': ')[1].strip() for v in data[1::3]]))` 4: `vol = list(map(float, [v.split(': ')[1].strip() for v in data[2::3]]))` 5: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` 6: `ax.plot(time, vol)` and then the axis formatting. [See code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jttb4.png)

Comment: Incidentally, your program was missing the first Current_Time, because it was `'ï»¿Current_Time: 2020-03-20 23:00:01\n'`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Your code works exactly as I had wanted mine to work. Last question, how to assign the xticks to occur on the dates such as: Mar 20 2020, Apr 20 2020, etc? Or how to assign specific dates.

Comment: As far as the format of the month, use %b instead of %B. How to pick specific dates might be a new question, though there’s probably an existing duplicate.

Comment: Add the following line `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=20, interval=1))` [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEaV8.png)